# Status Error in News APi on passing keywords

Tags: laravel

hy friends I am working on news api and after passing required keyword results an error , please guide me on this , why is this occuring andd what does i need to do ?

Array
(
    [status] => error
    [code] => parameterInvalid
    [message] => You are trying to request results too far in the past. Your plan permits you to request articles as far back as 2019-08-16, but you have requested 2019-08-16. To extend this please upgrade to a paid plan.
)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much self-explanatory. **Developer** version of the News Api allows search on articles not more than one month old. **Business** and **Enterprise** versions allow search on articles up to 12 months old.